# Avoid Adding Duplicate Records

Tags: loops, duplicates, abap

I m trying to write if statement to give error message if user try to add existing ID number.When i try to enter existing id i get error .untill here it s ok but when i type another id no and fill the fields(name,adress etc) it doesnt go to database.

```
METHOD add_employee.
    DATA: IT_EMP TYPE TABLE OF ZEMPLOYEE_20.
    DATA:WA_EMP TYPE ZEMPLOYEE_20.
    Data: l_count type i value '2'.

    SELECT * FROM ZEMPLOYEE_20 INTO TABLE IT_EMP.

    LOOP AT IT_EMP INTO WA_EMP.

      IF wa_emp-EMPLOYEE_ID eq pa_id.
        l_count = l_count * '0'.

      else.
        l_count = l_count * '1'.
      endif.
    endloop.

    If l_count eq '2'.

      WA_EMP-EMPLOYEE_ID = C_ID.
      WA_EMP-EMPLOYEE_NAME = C_NAME.
      WA_EMP-EMPLOYEE_ADDRESS = C_ADD.
      WA_EMP-EMPLOYEE_SALARY = C_SAL.
      WA_EMP-EMPLOYEE_TYPE = C_TYPE.
      APPEND wa_emp TO it_emp.
      INSERT ZEMPLOYEE_20 FROM TABLE it_emp.

      CALL FUNCTION 'POPUP_TO_DISPLAY_TEXT'
        EXPORTING
          TITEL     = 'INFO'
          TEXTLINE1 = 'Record Added Successfully.'.
          elseif l_count eq '0'.
      CALL FUNCTION 'POPUP_TO_DISPLAY_TEXT'
        EXPORTING
          TITEL     = 'INFO'
          TEXTLINE1 = 'Selected ID already in database.Please type another ID no.'.

    ENDIF.
ENDMETHOD.
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I'm getting your explanation. Why are you trying to re-insert all the existing entries back into the table? You're just trying to insert `C_ID` etc if it doesn't exist yet? Why do you need all the existing entries for that?

If so, throw out that select and the loop completely, you don't need it. You have a few options...

**Just read the table with your single entry**

```
SELECT SINGLE * FROM ztable INTO wa WITH KEY ID = C_ID etc.
IF SY-SUBRC = 0.
   "this entry exists. popup!
ENDIF.
```

**Use a modify statement**

This will overwrite duplicate entries with new data (so non key fields may change this way), it wont fail. No need for a popup.

```
MODIFY ztable FROM wa.
```

**Catch the SQL exceptions instead of making it dump**

If the update fails because of an exception, you can always catch it and deal with exceptional situations.

```
TRY .
    INSERT ztable FROM wa.
   CATCH sapsql_array_insert_duprec.
     "do your popup, the update failed because of duplicate records
ENDTRY.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a bug when appending in internal table 'IT_EMP' and inserting in 'ZEMPLOYEE_20' table.

Suppose you append the first time and then you insert. But when you append the second time you will have 2 records in 'IT_EMP' that are going to be inserted in 'ZEMPLOYEE_20'. That is because you don't refresh or clear the internal table and there you will have a runtime error.

According to [SAP documentation on 'Inserting Lines into Tables '](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_46c/helpdata/en/fc/eb3a6d358411d1829f0000e829fbfe/content.htm):

> Inserting Several Lines
>
> To insert several lines into a database table, use the following:
>   INSERT  FROM TABLE  [ACCEPTING DUPLICATE KEYS] . This
>   writes all lines of the internal table  to the database table in
>   one single operation. The same rules apply to the line type of 
>   as to the work area  described above. If the system is able to
>   insert all of the lines from the internal table, SY-SUBRC is set to 0.
>   If one or more lines cannot be inserted because the database already
>   contains a line with the same primary key, a runtime error occurs.

Maybe the right direction here is trying to insert the work area directly but before you must check if record already exists using the primary key.

Check the SAP documentation on this issue clicking the link before.

On the other hand, once `l_count` is zero because of `l_count = l_count * '0'.` that value will never change to any other number making that you won't append or insert again.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the insert query,if the sy-subrc is unsuccessful raise the error message.

```
WA_EMP-EMPLOYEE_ID = C_ID. 
WA_EMP-EMPLOYEE_NAME = C_NAME.
WA_EMP-EMPLOYEE_ADDRESS = C_ADD.
WA_EMP-EMPLOYEE_SALARY = C_SAL.
WA_EMP-EMPLOYEE_TYPE = C_TYPE. 
INSERT ZEMPLOYEE_20 FROM WA_EMP.
If sy-subrc <> 0.
  Raise the Exception.
Endif.
```

Answer (score 0):

why are you retrieving all entries from zemployee_20 ?

You can directly check wether the 'id' exists already or not by using select single. If exists, then show message, if not, add. 
It is recommended to retrieve only one field when its needed and not the entire table with asterisc *

```
SELECT single employee_id FROM ZEMPLOYEE_20 where employee_id = p_id INTO v_id. ( or field in structure )
if sy-subrc = 0. "exists
     "show message 
else. "not existing id
     "populate structure and then add record to Z table
endif.
```

Furthermore, l_count is not only unnecessary but also bad implemented.